# How can I change the Android spinner prompt style

Tags: android, android-spinner, prompt

I have developed an example. I need to change the style for Android spinner prompt. How can I change the style?

This is my **string.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, CustomizedListView!</string>
    <string name="app_name">CustomizedListView</string>
    <string name="status_prompt">Choose a Status</string>
</resources>
```

This code is used on my `main.xml`:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="106dp"
    android:layout_y="100dp"
    android:prompt="@string/status_prompt"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"/>
```

Here I want to change the background color and `textSize`, `textStyle` on the below image. How can I change this?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create your own `custom spinner`, refer to *[Android: Custom spinner with custom object!](http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html)*.

For background:

#### values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/StandardSpinner</item>
   </style>
</resources>

<style name="StandardSpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner</item>
</style>
```

#### Text size:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.textview);
```

You just have to change the design of the TextView you use of the spinner. I just tried with this, as the layout of the `textview.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:textSize="30sp"></TextView>
```

Comment: i wish to change the style for default spinner prompt background color and testSize,textStyle.this is my prompt <string name="status_prompt">Choose a Status</string> how is change the prompt style

Comment: Hi Lokesh  i have used your above code.the style is changes spinner item only it is doesnot change the spinner title text.

Comment: -1: This does not change the spinner prompt, which is what the user was asking for. Instead, it changes the style of the spinner list items.